# nautilus does not show samba share on network anymore

Tags: nautilus, samba, 16.10, shared-folders

**Nautilus** does not see anymore *samba share* on the network.

It was working before. Now I just got the circle spinning next to networks in nautilus.

Before that, I was able to seee them but unable to access them because it was taking ages and nothing was happening.

Before that, all was working fine.

And the only thing that happened is that I installed some packages to get the samba share running on my mahcine. I choosed "Share that folder" and installed the package required and asked by nautilus.

Edit: So I purged the package installed previously:

```
samba
samba-common
```

and it cascades in removing some others.
Still nothing

then I redo the install and this time purge all the package:

```
libaio1 python-dnspython python-ldb python-samba python-tdb samba-dsdb-modules samba-vfs-modules tdb-tools samba samba-common
```

and it's back instantly. But I got "can't access share place". But it's working manually by using connect to server.

hmm seems like a bug somewhere...

Comment: The packages you installed are listed by date and time in your dpkg.log. Please open it and review the log to determine what package you installed. Please [edit] that information into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!